What can I do to understand this better?
I am not sure how my code works.
def insertion_sort(array):
    print(f'Initiales Array: {array}')
    for i in range(1, len(array)):
        
        temp = array[i]
        j = i
        while j > 0 and array[j - 1] > temp:
            array[j] = array[j - 1]
            j -= 1
        array[j] = temp
        print(f'Nach i={i}, Array: {array}')
    return array

data = [4, 1, 8, -3, 5, 7]
insertion_sort(data)


i understand a liitle bit my loop but i get confused and i feel unsure

Use a debugger and step through the code.

there are many tutorials and youtube videos that explain insertion sort. What specific part you have trouble understanding?

It's not clear what help you want. There's a ton of stuff online about how to program in Python, and there's many explanations of insertion sort -- for example  on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort . Maybe you need to study these resources? A good question on stack-overflow is specific and has a clear right/wrong answer... you can read guidelines on https://stackoverflow.com/help . Asking vague "please help me" questions will not help you -- your questions will get downvotes and closed.

Try python tutor. Its great for stepping through line by line and watching what happens.

As explained above, you seem to have an expectation of what the code should do, so follow the execution using a debugger (visual, if possible) and see what is happening. Start from the first line. If you don't have any idea, then check how insertion sort works and compare against this code.

Let's break down this insertion sort algorithm step by step.
Step-by-Step Guide to Insertion Sort:

Initialization:

We start with an unsorted array.
In your example, data = [4, 1, 8, -3, 5, 7].


Iteration:

For each element from the second position (i = 1) to the end of the array:

Store the current element in a temporary variable (temp).
Initialize a pointer j to the current position (i).




Comparisons and Shifting:

While j > 0 and the element at position j-1 is greater than temp:

Shift the element at position j-1 one position to the right (move it to position j).
Decrement j by 1.




Insertion:

Place the original temp value in the correct position (array[j]).


Repeat:

Repeat steps 2-4 for all remaining elements.


Final Sorted Array:

The array is now sorted in ascending order.



Example Execution (using your data):

Initial array: [4, 1, 8, -3, 5, 7]
After the first iteration: [1, 4, 8, -3, 5, 7]
After the second iteration: [-3, 1, 4, 8, 5, 7]
After the third iteration: [-3, 1, 4, 5, 8, 7]
After the fourth iteration: [-3, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8]

Recommended Video Tutorial:
I recommend watching this video by CS Dojo on YouTube: Insertion Sort Algorithm Explained.
Remember, practice is key! Try implementing insertion sort in Python and experiment with different arrays to reinforce your understanding. Happy coding! 

So this is a classic algorithm called insertion sort:
First your code goes looks at each element of the array one by one sequentially. Done by:
for i in range(1, len(array))

Then it stores the value of that element in a separate variable for safe keeping as the array is going to be modified:
temp = array[i]

Then it loops back down the array from the current element and shuffles all of the elements forward. Provided that the element it is looking at is bigger than that temporary value
while j > 0 and array[j - 1] > temp:
   array[j] = array[j - 1]

The 2nd line in that block does the shuffling the first line does the looping portion
By shuffling all of the elements forward and ensuring that they are all bigger than temp, we now know that the element we are currently at is free and can store a smaller value than everything that has been shuffled. So we store that value back into the array at this element. Per the first sentence in this paragraph we have ensured that that element is in its sorted position and therefore once we have done that process for the whole array the array is now sorted
